# Pass function arguments to callback body in NoeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a question about variable scope in NodeJS.
Lets assume that we have a function (MainFunc) that calls another function (SecondFunc). The second function has a callback:

```
function MainFunc(arg1, arg2, arg3)
{
  SecondFunc(arg1, (respondJSON)
  {
    //AM I ALLOWED TO DO THE FOLLOWING?
    respondJSON.name = arg2;
    respondJSON.age = arg3;
  }
}
```

As you can see my sample code, `arg2` and `arg3` are used inside the callback body. Am I allowed to do this? Because the MainFunc might be called several time a second by many users, Are `arg2` and `arg3` GUARANTEED to be the same as the arguments or might be has another value that is call by another user, just before the callback is called?

Comment: In a nutshell: yes, this is fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. my question might be a bit different (at least from my viewpoint) from the aforementioned question. I wanted to know what happens to argument function if you use it inside a callback function.

Comment: You might want to read more about closures then; I've added some more duplicates.